# Keycloak Spring boot Error: Token type is incorrect. Expected 'Bearer' but was 'ID'

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, keycloak

I tried implementing Keycloak, using example from [here](https://github.com/cternes/slackspace-angular-spring-keycloak).
On Node.js it went ok, but I have a problem with Java Spring boot. After logging in (on the frontend) Keycloak returns token. After sending that token to the backend (Spring boot), I am getting an error "Token type is incorrect. Expected 'Bearer' but was 'ID'".
After decoding token I see that in the "typ" there is "ID", but probably should be "bearer". 
 
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?
All info are below:

Application.java

```
package bootwildfly;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping( "/hello")
    public String getProducts(){
        return ("Hello, SpringBoot on Wildfly");
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/logout")
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        request.logout();
        return "/";
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
keycloak.realm = Openshift-radionica
keycloak.bearer-only = true
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://keycloak-sso.***.***/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.resource = client-backend
server.port=8080

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] = user
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /hello/*
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>product-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>3.1.0.Final</keycloak.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0.CR2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Error:

```
2017-10-12 11:08:18.119 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Failed to verify token
org.keycloak.common.VerificationException: Token type is incorrect. Expected 'Bearer' but was 'ID'
    at org.keycloak.TokenVerifier$TokenTypeCheck.test(TokenVerifier.java:129) ~[keycloak-core-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.keycloak.TokenVerifier.verify(TokenVerifier.java:371) ~[keycloak-core-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.keycloak.RSATokenVerifier.verify(RSATokenVerifier.java:89) ~[keycloak-core-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterRSATokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterRSATokenVerifier.java:56) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterRSATokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterRSATokenVerifier.java:37) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticateToken(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:87) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.java:82) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.RequestAuthenticator.authenticate(RequestAuthenticator.java:68) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.authenticateInternal(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:206) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.authenticate(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:47) [spring-boot-container-bundle-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.doAuthenticate(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:54) [spring-boot-container-bundle-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:560) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:185) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-3.3.0.CR2.jar!/:3.3.0.CR2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar!/:8.5.14]
```

Comment: On the frontend , are you also using version 3.3.0.CR2 for the Keycloak JS library ?

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Comment: I know it's been awhile now but were you able to solve this? I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

On client side(frontend) I use VueJS [VueJS Keycloak](https://github.com/henriquesakata/vuejs-keycloak). I had the same problem. Solved this problem by changing src/components/security/header.js

```
import store from '../../store'
export default () => {
   var keycloakAuth = store.getters.SECURITY_AUTH
   return { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + keycloakAuth.idToken }
}
```

from keycloakAuth.idToken to keycloakAuth.token and it fixed problem.

Comment: Nice catch ! You should open an issue on the VueJS Keycloak repo so that the author can fix this.